# Comparison (1) in R function returns possible only for atomic or list types

Tags: r, function, operation

I have the following function:

```
 agegroup <- function(data, column) {

 setDT(data)

 if (class(data[[column]] == "integer")) {

  data[column <20, agegroup := "0-19"]
  data[column >= 20 & column < 25, agegroup := "20-24"]
  data[column >= 25 & column <30, agegroup := "25-29"]
  data[column >= 30 & column <35, agegroup := "30-34"]
  data[column >= 35 & column <40, agegroup := "35-39"]
  data[column >= 40 & column <45, agegroup := "40-44"]
  data[column >= 45 & column <50, agegroup := "45-49"]
  data[column >= 50 & column <55, agegroup := "50-54"]
  data[column >= 55 & column <60, agegroup := "55-59"]
  data[column >= 60 & column <65, agegroup := "60-64"]
  data[column >= 65 & column <70, agegroup := "65-69"]
  data[column >= 70 & column <75, agegroup := "70-74"]
  data[column >= 75 & column <80, agegroup := "75-79"]
  data[column >= 80 & column <85, agegroup := "80-84"]
  data[column >= 85, agegroup := "85+"]

  return(data)

  } else {

    print("Column type is not integer.")

  }
}
```

The function should check whether the referenced column is of integer type. However, when I do the comparison I get the following error:

```
Error in data[[column]] == integer : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Edit:

I placed the original function above.

Also, Sample of the data:

```
structure(list(age = c(87L, 70L, 69L, 68L, 68L, 68L)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Function call:

```
test <- agegroup(test, "age")
```

I'm not sure what is the problem.

Comment: I think there are two errors: the misplaced parentheses and the missing quotes. Try `class(data[[column]]) == "integer"`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent returns `argument is not interpretable as logical`

Comment: Please show `data` (paste the output of `dput(data)`) and your call to `new_function`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I have updated the question. Thanks for the assitence.

Comment: You didn't include the parentheses as @StéphaneLaurent wrote them.

Comment: That was the issue yes. I should have seen that. Thanks guys.

Comment: Seems like you should use `cut`